# Question on として in this sentence

Tags: grammar

もっと早くゲスト先生として迎えたかったのですが、なかなか長い時間がかかってしまってごめんなさい。

Translating to: 
= I wanted to have you as guest teachers earlier but I am sorry that it took a longer time than I had expected.

What exactly is the function, I have learned the volitional + とする means to attempt....but this is a noun

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing to me... What exactly is the function of what? What are you referring to as a noun? Are you looking for 迎えようとしたかった？

Comment: @user27280 I believe he's asking "What is the function of として" and also saying that "I learned the volitional form + とする means to attempt, but in this situation I have a noun + として". The noun being 先生 that is.

Comment: @Ringil Thanks. I wasn't paying enough attention to the question header.

Answer (score 4):

This として is not "the volitional + とする" but means "as" such as "He came to my school as an English teacher(彼は、私の学校に英語教師として来た。".

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate more on Yuuichi Tam's answer, it's "as", in the definition "in the role of" or "in the context of".  For example, to use Yuuichi Tam's example:

彼は、私の学校に英語教師として来た。 = "He came to my school as an English teacher" = "He came to my school in the role of an English teacher".